# Как плавно скрыть tr

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
<table>    
    <tr id="table_rows_1">
        <td>xxx</td>    
    </tr> 
</table>

$('#table_rows_1').hide(2000);
```

Пробовал так, все равно удаляет мгновенно. Как можно плавно скрыть/убрать/удалить?

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>    
    <tr id="table_rows_1">
        <td>xxx</td>    
    </tr> 
</table>

$('#table_rows_1').fadeOut(2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

А вот так не пробовали - $( "p" ).hide( "slow" ); ?

Тут есть пример - http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: видел,пробовал, не получилось.